# Mouse Click vs Mouse Release

Tags: javascript, events, click, mouse

What's the difference between the Mouse Click event to the Mouse Release event...since a Mouse Click is triggered when the button is pressed and released..and you need to press to release, this two events seem to be the same for me.

Answer (score 1):

These two events are not the same at all, it all depends on what you want your code to do. For example, try clicking on your browser close (X) and moving the mouse away from the (X) before you release the button. With a click event, your browser would close.